# How to determine what networking speeds my PC can support

Tags: networking

I am not sure if this is the correct forum to post this question?  I had a look and could not see where else I could post this type of question.

I have a C# desktop app. Its sole intent is to upload bytes to my server.

On 1 of my PC's the app performs well in terms of how fast the data uploads.
On another PC it does not perform so well.

When I look at Task Manager on each PC the Network activity for the 'fast' PC is 13Mbps.

The Network Activity for the 'slow' PC is 16kbps.

So, for me this explains the different speeds.

My question then is to find out WHY it is slower?  Is it to do with the Motherboard in terms of what it can support?

What other factors can affect the speed/rate of networking if both use the same type of Ethernet cables and both are attached to the router in the same way?

Thanks

Appendix:

On 'fast' PC:
[image]

On 'slow; PC:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are they both using the same model of network card?

Comment: @DavidPostill Hi. No they are not.  I have a 'USB 3.0 to 3 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter' for the 'slow' PC as it does not have an Ethernet port. However, as I am using that adapter it should support the same speeds? (I am a novice here)

Comment: What speeds are mentioned from the OS (I cannot assist you here, you do not mention which OS you use). Are both system connected to a switch? What speed did the network device supports. Is it possible to run a network speed test on every system?

Comment: Hi, OS on 'slow' PC is Windows 8.1. OS on 'fast' PC is Windows 7 Pro

Comment: What do the two different cards show in `Local Area Connection` -> `Properties` -> `Configure` -> `Advanced` -> `Speed & Duplex` or `Link Speed & Duplex`?

Comment: Are both system connected to a switch? both are connected to a hub which in turn is connected to a router (virgin Media)

Comment: @DavidPostill Under properties?

Comment: Right click `Local Area Connection` choose `Properties`. Can you provide screen shots showing the `Speed & Duplex`?

Comment: @DavidPostill could not see either of those properties. I have added an image to show you in case i am looking at the wrong place?

Comment: @ryder How would I do a Network Speed test? I can do an internet speed test but that is not the issue. The Network speed/baud is the issue i would have thought?

Comment: Select `Speed & Duplex` on the left then open the `value` drop down on the right to see the values it is set to.

Comment: @DavidPostill Hi, i just realized I could see that setting (not enough coffee this morning :))  It is on Auto Negotiation..

Comment: What is the output of `wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed` on each machine from a cmd prompt?

Comment: @DavidPostill, there is a tool called netio, with this you can measure then network throuput. See here e.g. http://www.msxfaq.de/tools/netio.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sides of the LAN link (router/switch & your computer) determine the speed of your connection.
For example, if your router is only capable of 100Mbit/sec then the maximum speed you can get is 100Mbit/sec (roughly 12.5MB/s).

You can view the speed your connection is working at by going to `Network & Sharing Center` > `Change Adapter Settings` > Right-Click your network adapter and click `Properties` > `Speed`.

As you can see from the below screenshot, my own LAN connection can receive/send data at a maximum of 100Mbit/sec:

[image]

The name of your network adapter can also help you with determining the maximum throughput of the adapter.

Mine can do up to 1 Gigabit/sec:

> Description: Intel(R) 82579V *Gigabit* Network Connection

Using your command, the `Speed` is shown in *bytes*. It can already be seen that both adapters can do up to 1 Gigabit/sec, but to be sure, we can do this calculation:

> MB = bytes/1000000

This gives us the answer of `1000` MB, 1000MB is a Gigabyte.

Comment: The author's device has a 10/100/1000 port based on the description of the device. This answer is the correct answer.